# How to set ASAN/UBSAN reporting output

Tags: gcc, clang, sanitizer, ubsan, address-sanitizer

I would like to run my unit test suite with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` and have all sanitizer errors be written to a `report.txt` file. By default all sanitizer errors get written to stdout, however the software also writes info to stdout so this makes it difficult to detect errors. I tried:

```
export ASAN_OPTIONS="log_path=asan.log"
./mytests
```

And I also tried calling the C API before running tests:

```
#include <sanitizer/asan_interface.h>

__sanitizer_set_report_path("/tmp/asan.log")
```

However neither seems to work, all errors just get written to stdout. I am using Debian testing:

```
root@94e239ad460a:~# gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.1.1-11) 6.1.1 20160802
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Is there any alternative method that I can save the sanitizer error from my unit tests somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Hm, I've successfully used log_path numerous times. If it does not work for you, please report a bug to ASan github (preferably with a minimal repro).

Answer (score 1):

I realize that my binaries were not having read permissions. A simple `chmod 500 <exe_path>` solved my problem.

Comment: Note that Asan [should have written an error message to stderr](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3ca75cd55030a53a858bdbe9aba6d87f6b1e90b8/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_file.cpp#L63) to diagnose that.

Answer (score 0):

What I always do is to make sure the directory exists.
You could use Qt:

```
QDir().mkpath("/tmp");
```

Asan will append a PID to your filename though, and I don't think you can disable that.

In my `common_interface_defs.h` there is only `__sanitizer_set_report_path` but I see that [gcc's master has a more recent function](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libsanitizer/include/sanitizer/common_interface_defs.h) where you pass on a file descriptor:

```
void __sanitizer_set_report_fd(void *fd);
```

You could check out if your platform's gcc/clang has the newer function to set a file descriptor.